# Using large textures with opengl on android

Tags: android, opengl-es

What is the best way to go about using large textures with opengl on android?

I want to load some background images for my game with my target resolution being 480x800. Going by the recommended 512x512 resolution cap, I've tried scaling the images down to 240x400 and having opengl scale them back up, but that looks like trash and I would rather keep them as high-res as possible. I've seen one or two other people talking about using 512x1024 so I'm wondering:

How many phones would actually have trouble handling these image sizes?

Would it be better to risk an OOM and use 512x1024 textures, or risk a performance hit by splitting the images in two and increasing opengl calls?

For consideration: In general I will only be using two other 512x512 atlases at a time (aside from the background), with a maximum of three on menu screens where framerate isn't important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experimented using large textures for for planets in my game. With two 1024x1024 hemispheres per planet and probably only one or max two planets visible at a time. Once in game, they render fine on my somewhat dated ZTE Blade running 2.1.

However, the load times were terrible (talking an extra 10 to 30 seconds for two large textures to load).

Comment: hmm the loading time is unfortunate but it's good to know it probably won't be a problem after that.